# Each person has a 60% chance of being dead and a 40% chance of being alive

Tags: jquery

Need help in jQuery creating an equation to get the result in random order.

Let's say we have 10 people.

Each person has a 60% chance of being dead and a 40% chance of being alive.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)?! Provide what code you currently have. Make some sort of effort.

Comment: I don't like those odds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/g2JMK/2/

```
function Person(isDead) {
    this.dead = isDead;
}

$(function(){
    var people = new Array();
    initPeople(people);
    $.each(people, function(){
        $('#foo').append('<p>' + this.dead + '</p>');
    });
});

function initPeople(people) {
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        people.push(new Person(Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) < 7));
    }
}
```

This line:

```
Math.ceil(Math.random()*10) < 7
```

gets a random number with a range of 10 and checks to see if it is less than 7. So 6 out of 10 = 60% chance of being true.